# MongoDB Autowired in custom classes

Tags: java, mongodb

I've got simple structure project:

com.database.mongodb.config.MongoConfig - MongoDB configuration used in @Import
com.database.mongodb.repository.ParameterRepository - interface which extends MongoRepository
com.server.main.MainClass - Main class of my program.

I just want to use my **ParameterRepository** everywhere I need it, for instance, in a custom class with some tasks in package **com.server.task.CustomClass**. I tried:

```
@Autowired
private ParameterRepository repo;
```

But it returns NullPointerException. I tried to create abstract class Task with annotation @Component, but it also doesn't work.

How can I make it possible?

My implementations:

**MongoConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.database.mongodb.repository"})
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("localhost:27017");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mydb";
    }
}
```

**ParameterRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface ParameterRepository extends MongoRepository<Parameter, Integer> {
}
```

**MainClass.class**

```
@Import(MongoConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SparkServer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private WeatherParameterRepo weatherParameterRepo;
...
```

Comment: What package is your `ParameterRepository` in?

Comment: @Adam It's **com.database.mongodb.repository.ParameterRepository** package. I'm wondering, how can I Inject or Autowire my Repository in custom class...

Comment: Well what package is your `MainClass` in? The `ParameterRepository` must be in a sub-package (or the same package) as your `MainClass` by default in order for Spring to create it.

Comment: So, if my `ParameterRepository` is in **com.database.mongodb.repository** and `MainClass` is in **com.server.main** I can't autowire? Maybe I could do a Controller to use `ParameterRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `ParameterRepository` to the `com.server.main` package (or a sub-package).

What you could also do is add `@ComponentScan({"com.database.mongodb.repository", "com.server.main"})` to your `MainClass` class.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I want to use `ParameterRepository` in my `MainClass` - I can easly do it, but If want to call `@Autowired private ParamtererRepository repo;` in my CustomClass, I've got NullPointer. I don't understand IoC by this example...

Comment: You need to make sure `CustomClass` is in a package that is getting scanned. Looks like it isn't as of now since its in `com.server.task`. Add that to the `@ComponentScan`, or change its package.